# Request Azure Active Directory token with limited scopes for Azure Service Management API

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, rbac

I use my app to request an oauth token from Azure AD for a user so that I can use the Azure Service Management API on behalf of the user to do things with their Azure resources. This works fine, however, **now I have *too much power*.**

I want to limit the scope of the tokens I retrieve to specific abilities so that I can't accidentally (or maliciously) do bad things to the Azure resources of the person my app impersonates.

The "Microsoft Graph" API has dozens of permissions I can grant:

[image: so many options]

but the "Windows Azure Service Management" API only has one: everything

[image: service management api permissions]

How can I make this access more granular to protect my app and my users?

Answer (score 1):

With the ASM API, you can't really limit the scope as far as I know.

Now the Azure Resource Management (ARM) API on the other hand allows very small granularity.
Is there a specific reason you would use the ASM API?

With ARM API, you would register an app, then give the app roles to the subscriptions/resource groups/resources, and it can then do those things.
Check the documentation for more info on ARM capabilities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/

Info on Role-based access control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview

Comment: If I go that route then I would have an app that would have narrow access to things through ARM/RBAC, which is great. I could limit it to managing Traffic Manager endpoints, for example. But now this narrow access isn't user-specific. Ideally I could both limit the app's access to what the person using it can do (_their_ traffic management endpoints), and further limit it to the types of actions I specifically grant to the app (_enable or disable_, not delete), resulting in an even narrow set of abilities.

Comment: Yeah so in this case there is no delegation. That is true.